# Strong Name Validation Failed on CRM 2016 GeneratePicklistEnums

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm

I am starting a new project on a new Windows 10 computer working on CRM 2016 and have some strange behavior. I needed to generate the enumerations of the picklists for my code so I used the GeneratePicklistEnums project from the 2016 SDK SampleCode folder. I created the signing certificate on the project properties, ran build, and modified the .bat file (as I have done with past versions) and when I run the batch file I get this error:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.CrmSvcUtil.Main(String[] args)

I read a bunch of blogs and MS community posts on turning off strong name checking and adding exceptions - none of them worked.

I looked at the AssemblyInfo.cs and didn't see any reference to the AssemblyKeyFile so I added one - didn't make a difference. I tried several things with sn.exe, including "sn -Vr *" but that didn't work either. I used ildasm to inspect the GeneratePicklistEnums.dll and it showed as version 0.0.0.0 and all the referenced assemblies did have version numbers.

Any suggestions?

--- update:
I finally got the code to run by going back to the SDK and copying the following files from that BIN folder into my project BIN folder:

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl
Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
```

but it still is not getting a version or strong name.

Comment: You copied them into your bin folder?  Try updating your project references to point to the dlls in the SDK's bin folder (even better, use the assemblies available on nuget).  Also, you say you got your code to run but it's still not getting a version or strong name....are you saying that your code got farther than it did last time but you're still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The CRM SDK Toolkit has 2 different folders with CrmSvcUtil.exe. If you use the one under \SampleCode\CS\CrmSvcUtilExtensions\GeneratePicklistEnums\bin\Debug, you will get the error message. However, if you use the one under \bin, it will work.

Just ensure that in your command or batch file, you use the absolute path to the [CRMSDK]\bin\CrmSvcUtil.exe

Answer (score -1):

There is an open source tool for the [XrmToolbox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) called the [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator) from Daryl LaBar, which is just a wrapper on top of crmsvcutil from the SDK.  Save yourself the trouble and use that tool, it has a lot of nice features baked in.  Btw, with the latest versions of the toolbox, there is a plugin "store" so you don't even have to download the EBG manually anymore.

Comment: I love the XRMToolbox and have used it for some time. In this case, I wanted to make this program work stand-alone so I could automate the update to the optionsets.cs file

Comment: You're in luck...the Early Bound Generator outputs a crmsvcutil command that you can use to regenerate your file from the command line, including all the options you choose, without running the toolbox.

Comment: I got that - the problem I was trying to solve (which I think I have - see  my revision above) was that the OOTB Sample Code project to generate the early bound class was not working until I replaced the DLL's in that project with the DLL's (above) from the SDK bin folder.

Comment: How is this solving the problem? XRMToolbox is good, but that just sidesteps the problem Eccountable is having, and does not help anyone looking at this post in the future.